# Implementing a DLL callback in Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll, callback, delphi-10-seattle

I am trying to interface to a Software Defined Receiver DLL that needs to be given a callback to deliver received I/Q data.

I can call the DLL fine, but I cannot figure out how to code the callback.

This is part of the main Module:

```
uses
  uReceiverHackRFDLLWrapper;

procedure TForm1.btnIDClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  strptr: PAnsiChar;
begin
  hackrf_board_init();
  strptr := hackrf_board_id_name(0);
  lblName.Caption := 'Name: ' + strptr;
end;
```

This is the wrapper for the DLL:

```
unit uReceiverHackRFDLLWrapper;

interface

uses Windows, uSETITypes, sysutils;

{$MINENUMSIZE 4}

type
  // Trtlsdr_read_async_cb_t = procedure(buf: PAnsiChar; len: UINT32; ctx: Pointer);
  // [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  // public unsafe delegate int hackrf_sample_block_cb_fn(hackrf_transfer* ptr); /* Return 0 if OK or -1 if error to stop */
  THackrf_sample__block_cb_fn = function(var hackrf_transfer: Pointer): integer;

function hackrf_board_id_name(index: integer): Pointer; stdcall;
function hackrf_board_init(): integer; stdcall;
function hackrf_open(var dev: THackRF_dev): integer; stdcall;

function hackrf_start_rx(dev: THackRF_dev; cb: THackrf_sample__block_cb_fn; rx_ctx: Pointer): integer;

implementation

var
  DLLLoaded: Boolean = False;
  SaveExit: Pointer;
  DLLHandle: THandle;

function SampleCallBack(var hackrf_transfer: Pointer): integer;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  i := 12345;
end;

function GetModuleFileNameStr(Instance: THandle): string;
var
  buffer: array [0 .. MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  GetModuleFileName(Instance, buffer, MAX_PATH);

  Result := extractfilepath(buffer);
end;

function hackrf_board_id_name; external 'libhackrf.dll' name 'hackrf_board_id_name';
function hackrf_board_init; external 'libhackrf.dll' name 'hackrf_init';
function hackrf_open; external 'libhackrf.dll' name 'hackrf_open';

// [DllImport(LibHackRF, EntryPoint = "hackrf_start_rx", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
// public static extern int hackrf_start_rx(IntPtr dev, hackrf_sample_block_cb_fn cb, IntPtr rx_ctx);
function hackrf_start_rx; external 'libhackrf.dll' name 'hackrf_start_rx';

initialization

DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('libhackrf.dll');

end.
```

Anyone have a simple example of this callback that I can use?

Comment: This is rather hard to understand. It would be good if you could cut it down. You haven't addressed calling convention for call back. We can only see some of the types.

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: since all Dll funcs are stdcall, the callback should be stdcall also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [libHackRF API documentation](https://github.com/mossmann/hackrf/wiki/libHackRF-API) and [source code](https://github.com/mossmann/hackrf/tree/master/host/libhackrf/src), there are a few errors in the wrapper unit.

First, all of the DLL functions use `cdecl` as the calling convention on Windows, *not* `stdcall`.

Second, the `hackrf_start_rx()` function is not declared with any calling convention, so it uses Delphi's default `register` convention.  Same with `THackrf_sample__block_cb_fn`.  You need to add `cdecl` to their declarations.

Third, using `var Pointer` for the `hackrf_transfer` parameter of `THackrf_sample__block_cb_fn` does not match the signature of the actual `hackrf_sample_block_cb_fn` callback type.  The correct callback declaration should be more like this instead:

```
THackrf_sample__block_cb_fn = function(var ptr: hackrf_transfer): integer; cdecl;
```

Where `hackrf_transfer` itself needs to be declared something like this (assuming it is not already declared in the `uSETITypes` unit):

```
type
  phackrf_device = ^hackrf_device;
  hackrf_device = record
  end;

  ...

  hackrf_transfer = record
    device: phackrf_device;
    buffer: PByte;
    buffer_length: Integer;
    valid_length: Integer;
    rx_ctx: Pointer;
    tx_ctx: Pointer;
  end;
```

Where did `Trtlsdr_read_async_cb_t` come from?  That is not part of the API.

Now with all of that said, a proper wrapper unit should look something more like this instead:

```
unit uHackRF;

interface

{$MINENUMSIZE 4}

type
  hackrf_error = (
    HACKRF_SUCCESS = 0,
    HACKRF_TRUE = 1,
    HACKRF_ERROR_INVALID_PARAM = -2,
    HACKRF_ERROR_NOT_FOUND = -5,
    HACKRF_ERROR_BUSY = -6,
    HACKRF_ERROR_NO_MEM = -11,
    HACKRF_ERROR_LIBUSB = -1000,
    HACKRF_ERROR_THREAD = -1001,
    HACKRF_ERROR_STREAMING_THREAD_ERR = -1002,
    HACKRF_ERROR_STREAMING_STOPPED = -1003,
    HACKRF_ERROR_STREAMING_EXIT_CALLED = -1004,
    HACKRF_ERROR_OTHER = -9999,
  );

  hackrf_board_id = (
    BOARD_ID_JELLYBEAN  = 0,
    BOARD_ID_JAWBREAKER = 1,
    BOARD_ID_HACKRF_ONE = 2,
    BOARD_ID_INVALID = 0xFF,
  );

  hackrf_usb_board_id = (
    USB_BOARD_ID_JAWBREAKER = 0x604B,
    USB_BOARD_ID_HACKRF_ONE = 0x6089,
    USB_BOARD_ID_RAD1O = 0xCC15,
    USB_BOARD_ID_INVALID = 0xFFFF,
  );

  rf_path_filter = (
    RF_PATH_FILTER_BYPASS = 0,
    RF_PATH_FILTER_LOW_PASS = 1,
    RF_PATH_FILTER_HIGH_PASS = 2,
  );

  transceiver_mode_t = (
    TRANSCEIVER_MODE_OFF = 0,
    TRANSCEIVER_MODE_RX = 1,
    TRANSCEIVER_MODE_TX = 2,
    TRANSCEIVER_MODE_SS = 3,
    TRANSCEIVER_MODE_CPLD_UPDATE = 4
  );

  phackrf_device = ^hackrf_device;
  hackrf_device = record
  end;

  hackrf_transfer = record
    device: phackrf_device;
    buffer: PByte;
    buffer_length: Integer;
    valid_length: Integer;
    rx_ctx: Pointer;
    tx_ctx: Pointer;
  end;

  read_partid_serialno_t = record
    part_id: array[0..1] of UInt32;
    serial_no: array[0..3] of UInt32;
  end;

  hackrf_device_list = record
    serial_numbers: PPAnsiChar;
    usb_board_ids: ^hackrf_usb_board_id;
    usb_device_index: PInteger;
    devicecount: Integer;

    usb_devices: PPointer;
    usb_devicecount: Integer;
  end;

  hackrf_device_list_t = hackrf_device_list;
  phackrf_device_list_t = ^hackrf_device_list_t;

  hackrf_sample_block_cb_fn = function(var transfer: hackrf_transfer): Integer; cdecl;

function hackrf_init: Integer; cdecl;
function hackrf_exit: Integer; cdecl;

function hackrf_device_list: phackrf_device_list_t; cdecl;
function hackrf_device_list_open(list: phackrf_device_list_t; idx: Integer; var device: phackrf_device): Integer; cdecl;
procedure hackrf_device_list_free(list: phackrf_device_list_t); cdecl;

function hackrf_open(var device: phackrf_device): Integer; cdecl;
function hackrf_open_by_serial(const desired_serial_number: PAnsiChar; var device: phackrf_device): Integer; cdecl;;
function hackrf_close(device: phackrf_device): Integer; cdecl;

function hackrf_start_rx(device: phackrf_device; callback: hackrf_sample_block_cb_fn; rx_ctx: Pointer): Integer; cdecl;
function hackrf_stop_rx(device: phackrf_device): Integer; cdecl;

function hackrf_start_tx(device: phackrf_device; callback: hackrf_sample_block_cb_fn; tx_ctx: Pointer): Integer; cdecl;
function hackrf_stop_tx(device: phackrf_device): Integer; cdecl;

{ return HACKRF_TRUE if success }
function hackrf_is_streaming(device: phackrf_device): Integer; cdecl;

function hackrf_max2837_read(device: phackrf_device; register_number: UInt8; var value: UInt16): Integer; cdecl;
function hackrf_max2837_write(device: phackrf_device; register_number: UInt8; value: UInt16): Integer; cdecl;

function hackrf_si5351c_read(device: phackrf_device; register_number: UInt16; var value: UInt16): Integer; cdecl;
function hackrf_si5351c_write(device: phackrf_device; register_number: UInt16; value: UInt16): Integer; cdecl;

function hackrf_set_baseband_filter_bandwidth(device: phackrf_device; const bandwidth_hz: UInt32): Integer; cdecl;

function hackrf_rffc5071_read(device: phackrf_device; register_number: UInt8; var value: UInt16): Integer; cdecl;
function hackrf_rffc5071_write(device: phackrf_device; register_number: UInt8; value: UInt16): Integer; cdecl;

function hackrf_spiflash_erase(device: phackrf_device): Integer; cdecl;
function hackrf_spiflash_write(device: phackrf_device; const address: UInt32; const length: UInt16; const data: PByte): Integer; cdecl;
function hackrf_spiflash_read(device: phackrf_device; const address: UInt32; const length: UInt16; data: PByte): Integer; cdecl;

{ device will need to be reset after hackrf_cpld_write }
function hackrf_cpld_write(device: phackrf_device; const data: PByte; const total_length: UInt32): Integer; cdecl;

function hackrf_board_id_read(device: phackrf_device; var value: UInt8): Integer; cdecl;
function hackrf_version_string_read(device: phackrf_device; version: PAnsiChar; length: UInt8): Integer; cdecl;

function hackrf_set_freq(device: phackrf_device; const freq_hz: UInt64): Integer; cdecl;
function hackrf_set_freq_explicit(device: phackrf_device; const if_freq_hz, lo_freq_hz: UInt64; const path: rf_path_filter): Integer; cdecl;

{ currently 8-20Mhz - either as a fraction, i.e. freq 20000000hz divider 2 -> 10Mhz or as plain old 10000000hz (double)
    preferred rates are 8, 10, 12.5, 16, 20Mhz due to less jitter }
function hackrf_set_sample_rate_manual(device: phackrf_device; const freq_hz, divider: UInt32): Integer; cdecl;
function hackrf_set_sample_rate(device: phackrf_device; const freq_hz: Double): Integer; cdecl;

{ external amp, bool on/off }
function hackrf_set_amp_enable(device: phackrf_device; const value: UInt8): Integer; cdecl;

function hackrf_board_partid_serialno_read(device: phackrf_device; var read_partid_serialno: read_partid_serialno_t): Integer; cdecl;

{ range 0-40 step 8d, IF gain in osmosdr  }
function hackrf_set_lna_gain(device: phackrf_device; value: UInt32): Integer; cdecl;

{ range 0-62 step 2db, BB gain in osmosdr }
function hackrf_set_vga_gain(device: phackrf_device; value: UInt32): Integer; cdecl;

{ range 0-47 step 1db }
function hackrf_set_txvga_gain(device: phackrf_device; value: UInt32): Integer; cdecl;

{ antenna port power control }
function hackrf_set_antenna_enable(device: phackrf_device; const value: UInt8): Integer; cdecl;

function hackrf_error_name(errcode: hackrf_error): PAnsiChar; cdecl;
function hackrf_board_id_name(board_id: hackrf_board_id): PAnsiChar; cdecl;
function hackrf_usb_board_id_name(usb_board_id: hackrf_usb_board_id): PAnsiChar; cdecl;
function hackrf_filter_path_name(const path: rf_path_filter): PAnsiChar; cdecl;

{ Compute nearest freq for bw filter (manual filter) }
function hackrf_compute_baseband_filter_bw_round_down_lt(const bandwidth_hz: UInt32): UInt32; cdecl;
{ Compute best default value depending on sample rate (auto filter) }
function hackrf_compute_baseband_filter_bw(const bandwidth_hz: UInt32): UInt32;

implementation

const
  LibHackRF = 'libhackrf.dll';

function hackrf_init; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_init';
function hackrf_exit; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_exit';

function hackrf_device_list; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_device_list';
function hackrf_device_list_open; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_device_list_open';
procedure hackrf_device_list_free; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_device_list_free';

function hackrf_open; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_open';
function hackrf_open_by_serial; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_open_by_serial';
function hackrf_close; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_close';

function hackrf_start_rx; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_start_rx';
function hackrf_stop_rx; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_stop_rx';

function hackrf_start_tx; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_start_tx';
function hackrf_stop_tx; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_stop_tx';

function hackrf_is_streaming; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_is_streaming';

function hackrf_max2837_read; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_max2837_read';
function hackrf_max2837_write; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_max2837_write';

function hackrf_si5351c_read; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_si5351c_read';
function hackrf_si5351c_write; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_si5351c_write';

function hackrf_set_baseband_filter_bandwidth; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_set_baseband_filter_bandwidth';

function hackrf_rffc5071_read; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_rffc5071_read';
function hackrf_rffc5071_write; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_rffc5071_write';

function hackrf_spiflash_erase; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_spiflash_erase';
function hackrf_spiflash_write; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_spiflash_write';
function hackrf_spiflash_read; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_spiflash_read';

function hackrf_cpld_write; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_cpld_write';

function hackrf_board_id_read; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_board_id_read';
function hackrf_version_string_read; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_version_string_read';

function hackrf_set_freq; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_set_freq';
function hackrf_set_freq_explicit; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_set_freq_explicit';

function hackrf_set_sample_rate_manual; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_set_sample_rate_manual';
function hackrf_set_sample_rate; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_set_sample_rate';

function hackrf_set_amp_enable; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_set_amp_enable';

function hackrf_board_partid_serialno_read; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_board_partid_serialno_read';

function hackrf_set_lna_gain; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_set_lna_gain';

function hackrf_set_vga_gain; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_set_vga_gain';

function hackrf_set_txvga_gain; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_set_txvga_gain';

function hackrf_set_antenna_enable; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_set_antenna_enable';

function hackrf_error_name; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_error_name';
function hackrf_board_id_name; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_board_id_name';
function hackrf_usb_board_id_name; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_usb_board_id_name';
function hackrf_filter_path_name; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_filter_path_name';

function hackrf_compute_baseband_filter_bw_round_down_lt; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_compute_baseband_filter_bw_round_down_lt';
function hackrf_compute_baseband_filter_bw; external LibHackRF name 'hackrf_compute_baseband_filter_bw';

end.
```

NOW, you can write a callback:

```
uses
  uHackRF;

var
  device: phackrf_device = nil;

type
  ELibHackRFError = class(Exception)
  public
    ErrorCode: Integer;
    constructor CreateError(Err: Integer);
  end;

  constructor ELibHackRFError.CreateError(Err: Integer);
  begin
    inherited CreateFmt('LibHackRF Error %d', [Err]);
    ErrorCode := Err;
  end;

function HackRFCheck(Res: Integer);
begin
  if Res < 0 then
    raise ELibHackRFError.CreateError(Res);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HackRFCheck(hackrf_init());
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if device <> nil then
    hackrf_close(device);
  hackrf_exit();
end;

procedure TForm1.btnIDClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  strptr: PAnsiChar;
begin
  strptr := hackrf_board_id_name(BOARD_ID_JELLYBEAN);
  lblName.Caption := 'Name: ' + StrPas(strptr);
end;

function RxCallback(var transfer: hackrf_transfer): Integer; cdecl;
begin
  // use transfer members as needed...
  // transfer.rx_ctx is a pointer to the TForm1 object...
  //...
  Result := HACKRF_SUCCESS;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnOpenClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if device = nil then
    HackRFCheck(hackrf_open(device)); // or hackrf_device_list_open() or hackrf_open_by_serial()
end;

procedure TForm1.btnCloseClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if device <> nil then
  begin
    HackRFCheck(hackrf_close(device));
    device = nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnStartRxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if device <> nil then
    HackRFCheck(hackrf_start_rx(device, RxCallback, Self));
end;

procedure TForm1.btnStopRxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if device <> nil then
    HackRFCheck(hackrf_stop_rx(device));
end;
```

Comment: Remy - Thanks for your input. Translating API calls is difficult, to say the least. I did have one problem, though.

Should not the Device List look like this:

    hackrf_device_list_t = record

Then

   // hackrf_device_list_t = hackrf_device_list;

Comment: @SetiNet you *can* do it that way. What I showed is a *literal* translation. The API declares an actual `hackrf_device_list` struct and then declares a `hackrf_device_list_t` alias for it. So I did the same.

Comment: That's the part that is confusing me. The API name for the struct is hackrf_device_list_t. I can't find that alias at all.

Comment: @SetiNet `hackrf_device_list_t` **is** the alias: `typedef struct hackrf_device_list hackrf_device_list_t;`